# Unable to Downloading zip file

Tags: java, zip

I have been trying to make this code work and also browsed stackoverflow for a while now but not able to find the answer. Hope you can help.

Trying to download a zip file from internet however it result in a zip file of 1 kb.

update: i have tried Long.MAX_VALUE, but the result is the same. I'm really not sure what is wrong. Normal text files works just file, but not zipfiles. PLease help.

```
private static void testDownload() {

    try {
        URL website = new URL("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1027884/000102788418000013/0001027884-18-000013-xbrl.zip");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\0001027884-18-000013-xbrl.zip");
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `1024` bytes to be precise, which is exactly what you tell the program to do.

Comment: What do you think `fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1024);` is doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Using transferFrom() is potentially much more efficient than a simple loop that reads from the source channel and writes to this channel. Many operating systems can transfer bytes directly from the source channel into the filesystem cache without actually copying them.

Note: The third parameter in transferFrom is the maximum number of bytes to transfer. Integer.MAX_VALUE will transfer at most 2^31 bytes, Long.MAX_VALUE will allow at most 2^63 bytes (larger than any file in existence).

So , Here as you are specifying 1024 , i think thats why your zip file size is 1 KB .   Please try specifying Long.MAX_VALUE .

Hope this solves your problem .

Comment: Dear Sahil, Thanks. However i've tried Long.MAX_VALUE earlier but the result was the same. 1kb file zip file

Comment: Guys, i have tried several codes. Stil the same results. It always results in a zip file of 1 kb with the following file with the content : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1035443/000103544317000022/0001035443-17-000022-xbrl.zip%22">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.sec.gov Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, finally found the problem based on the output in the zipfiles.

Only had to convert HTTP to HTTPS which solved the problem

Comment: Ok , So browser is automatically converting the request to https that's why we were able to download it from browser .